# Common Lisp - get length of nested vector

Tags: arrays, vector, common-lisp

I have a data structure:

```
*game-board*

#(#() #() #() #() #() #() #())
CL-USER> (test-move)
1
CL-USER> *game-board*
#(("O" "X" . #()) ("O" "X" . #()) ("X" "O" "O" "X" . #())
  ("X" "O" "X" "O" . #()) ("O" "X" . #()) ("X" . #()) ("X" "O" . #()))
CL-USER> (print-game-board)

("O" "X" . #()) 
("O" "X" . #()) 
("X" "O" "O" "X" . #()) 
("X" "O" "X" "O" . #()) 
("O" "X" . #()) 
("X" . #()) 
("X" "O" . #()) 
NIL
CL-USER>
```

My question is how do I get the dimensions of the inner vectors?

(array-dimension *game-board* 0) returns 7 for the length of the outer vector. How ever I can't figure out how to get the dimensions of the inner vectors.

my code that fills the board is this: (run once for every input)

```
(defun move (c)
  (let ((place (gethash c *col-lookup*)))
    (cond ((oddp *turn-count*)
           (push "X" (aref *game-board* place))
           (incf *turn-count*))
          ((push "O" (aref *game-board* place))
           (incf *turn-count*)))))
```

I used vectors because I figured I could just push moves onto the board and when checking if the length was less then 4 then just skip the horizontal check for that row.

Am I thinking about optimizing even before I have a solution? That's probably unwise, I probably should just hack something together using a 2d array as suggested.

Comment: Just use a 2d array. You don't need to use a vector of vectors in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you you have no inner vectors. Although you start with with a vector of with with 7 vectors, after (test-move) you have a vector with 7 improper lists whose last element is a #(). Can you add the code to test-move so we can help you see what went wrong there?

Btw, I'm guessing you are using a list of lists representation when you want to represent a grid? If so may I suggest using a multidimensional array or just a vector and some helper functions to move from a pair to an index and back.

Answer (score 0):

The inner arrays might not be all have the same dimension, so here's an example that gives you the largest dimension:

```
(defun inner-dimension (outer-array)
  (loop for inner-array being the elements of outer-array
        maximize (array-dimension inner-array 0)))
```

If you want the inner arrays to be all the same size, you should use a single multi-dimensional array instead of an array of arrays.